# ... но фактически как человек убит. Пунктуация

Tags: пунктуация

> 1. Человек живёт физически, но фактически () **как человек** ()
>    убит. Он сошёл с ума. Результат травли!

Какие варианты постановки знаков препинания здесь возможны? И почему?
Можно "**как человек**" не брать в запятые/тире совсем?

> 2. Он () **как человек добрый и милосердный** () был приглашён ими на работу.

Вопрос такой же. И "**как человек добрый и милосердный**" можно в запятые/тире совсем не брать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По правилам эта задача решается без особого труда. Здесь нет значения уподобления (художественного сравнения), но есть значение **приравнивания** (тождества, другими словами).

Розенталь:  http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=147#pp147 § 42. Сравнительный оборот

1. *Человек живёт физически, но фактически **как человек** убит. Он сошёл с ума. Результат травли!* Это значение "в качестве", нет обособления.

Розенталь, пункт 4. Сравнительный оборот с союзом как не выделяется запятыми:
2) если основное значение оборота — приравнивание или отождествление: *Ты любил меня как собственность, как источник радостей, тревог и печалей* (Л.) — ср.: …любил меня, считая своей собственностью (‘отождествляя меня со своей собственностью’); *Старайтесь смотреть на меня как на пациента, одержимого болезнью, вам ещё неизвестной* (Л.) — ср.: …приравнивая меня к своим пациентам.

2. *Он, **как человек добрый и милосердный,** был приглашён ими на работу.* Здесь значение причины, оборот обособляется. Проверка: будучи человеком добрым и милосердным...  Видно, именно такие люди нужны на этой работе.

Розенталь, пунт 3 (1). Сравнительный оборот с союзом как выделяется запятыми в следующих случаях:
Сравнительный оборот может содержать в себе оттенок **причинного значения:** *Васенда, как человек положительный и практический, нашёл невыгодным закреплённое место* (Пом.) — ‘будучи человеком положительным’...

3. Фактически это одна и та же тема, только во втором случае оборот следует обособить, чтобы подчеркнуть  его причинное значение (актуализация оборота).

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133766/discussion-on-answer-by-sharon------).

Comment: А вы логические ударения уже не учитываете? И вклинивание в структуру не замечаете. Странно.

Comment: Завтра начну учитывать, а сейчас спать пора. А вклинивание в структуру – это что за термин такой? Ваше изобретение?

Comment: Странно, мы эти вещи не раз обсуждали. Например: *Скажу, как врач, вам вот что.* Оборот вклинивается в предложение. Процесс не может быть термином. Предложите своё название.

Comment: Это позиция, рекомендуемая для обособления.  Интонация простого предложения не соответствует такой структуре.

Comment: Ну понятно. А как назвать? Вам же не нравится "вклинивание в структуру". И в примере из вопроса такое же, просто завуалированное. Но логические ударения тут же раскрывают маскировку. Даже подставлять ничего не надо.

Comment: Да я не помню, что обсуждали, завтра посмотрю.

Comment: Когда-то давно. Вы тоже про вклинивание говорили. Жаль, что поиск не ищет в комментариях.

Comment: Там даже паузы ощущаются. Отождествлять человека с человеком точно не вариант.

Comment: Второй пункт у вас верный, а вот первый — нет. Только первый пример имел в виду.

Comment: А при обособлении что меняется - тот же человек, как человек. А слово фактически относится к "убит". Живет физически, но фактически убит как человек. Тоже будете обособлять?

Comment: У вас получается "человек как человек", это ерунда. Но дело в ударениях. Одно ударение падает на оборот, а другое — на последнее слово, в связи с этим нужно обособить. Сравните: *Как человЕк вам говорю. Говорю, как человЕк, вам слЕдующее.*

Comment: У меня ударение в обоих случаях падает на человека, что важно. А ваш человек уточняет не пойми чего (слово фактически). К тому же здесь вставочная интонация, а она ударения не гарантирует: прочитать по-разному  можно.  К вашему сведению ударение на конечном слове логическим не бывает, там обычно ударение, характерное для конца фразы.

Comment: Нет там уточнения. Это вклинивание в структуру, либо причинное значение. Без ударения на "убит" прочитать сложно, а лишь тогда запятые не нужны.

Comment: Да ради бога, заблуждайтесь и дальше :))  У обособленных конструкций двойная семантика: или подчеркивание важного, или обозначение дополнительных сведений.  Что именно в конкретном случае (как читать)  – как говорится, догадайся сам.

Comment: Может, вы иначе интерпретируете, но точно не так, как надо. У меня такие ударения: *...но фактИчески, как человЕк, убИт*. И без интонации уточнения.

Comment: А я читаю так:  ...но фактИчески, как человек, убИт.   У меня в данном случае это позиция вводных слов, а они не имеют полноценного ударения.  А мой вариант чтения: ...но фактически как человЕк убит.

Comment: В любом случае должно быть ударение на обороте (хоть маленькое), это вам не вводное слово. Если без запятых, то известно, что убит, просто говорят, как кто именно. Или же нужно ударение на "убит". И у вас получается "человек убит как человек", это ерунда. Всё равно что "собака бегает как собака".

Answer (score 0):

Оборот со значение ‟в качестве” не обособляется, только если стоит в конце предложения (первостепенен для смысла) и произносится не как присоединение (дополнение к уже завершённому предложению с соответствующей паузой). Примеры из Розенталя:

> Ленский везде был принят как жених (П.).
> Я говорю как литератор (М. Г.).
> Мы знаем Индию как страну древнейшей культуры.
> Я сохраню это письмо как память.
> Полученный ответ рассматривается как согласие (Аж.).
> Читающая публика успела привыкнуть к Чехову как юмористу (Фед.).

Если же он не находится в конце предложения, то обособляется. Примеры из Розенталя:

> Илюше иногда, как резвому мальчику, так и хочется броситься и переделать всё самому (Гонч.).
> Как старый артиллерист, я презираю этот вид холодного украшения (Ш.).
> Леонтьев увлёкся этой мыслью, но, как человек осторожный, пока что о ней никому не рассказывал (Пауст.).

В справочнике есть еще два таких примера, но объясняется это причинным значением:

> Рецензируемую книгу можно рекомендовать как пособие для студентов.
> Следует признать, что, как пособие для студентов, рецензируемая книга имеет ряд существенных недостатков. **(Оборот не имеет причинного значения, но обособляется).**

В справочнике Лопатина есть такое примечание:

> Приложение с союзом как надо отличать от оборота со значением «в качестве». Ср.: Он, как инженер, должен быть руководителем стройки (будучи инженером, должен руководить; приложение). — Он приехал на стройку как инженер (в качестве инженера; см. § 90).

В общем, в справочнике напрямую не говорится об этом правиле, но я не видел примера, который бы противоречил ему.

В итоге, мой ответ таков:
**1. Человек живёт физически, но фактически, как человек, убит. Он сошёл с ума. Результат травли!**

**2. Он, как человек добрый и милосердный, был приглашён ими на работу.**

**ИСКЛЮЧЕНИЕ:**
Также у этого правила есть одно исключение: в качестве обороты не обособляются, когда находятся не в конце предложения, но это предложение с непрямым порядком слов от такого предложения, где в качестве оборот находится в конце. Взгляните на примеры:

> Говорю вам как врач = Как врач вам говорю.
> Я как литератор говорю = Я говорю как литератор.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133789/discussion-on-answer-by-jim-korbett------).