# Как больная шизофренией() я освобождена

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

> Как больная шизофренией(,) я освобождена от проверки тетрадей и
> классного руководства! Зато все мои ученики поступили на мехмат МГУ!

Запятая нужна, т.к. здесь "причина-следствие" смысл, а не "в качестве"?

Comment: Нет, здесь позиция играет роль. Такие обороты обычно обособляются в начале предложения. В конце бы не обособлялось.

Comment: Главное - позиция, это я поняла! Это, наверное, есть у Розенталя где-нибудь.

Comment: Да, есть. В теме про сравнительный оборот.

Comment: Это хорошо! Хорошо, что Вы есть...

Comment: Хотя нет, оно есть в теме про [обособление деепричастий](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=113) в пункте 7. А здесь такой же принцип. Это зависит от логических ударений. Когда одно ударение, запятая не нужна, а когда два — нужна. Это зависит от самого предложения, а не от желания автора. Но у Розенталя это объясняется "причинным оттенком значения", что не очень помогает понять. Но порой этот причинный оттенок важен. В этой теме много нюансов, и на этом сайте она считается одной из самых сложных.

Comment: Большое спасибо!!!

Comment: [Здесь](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/470086) Jim Korbett пытался классифицировать случаи по этой теме. Под его ответом есть ссылка на дискуссию c ним и мной. Но там обсуждаются самые сложные моменты этой сложной темы.